# How to close the utility bar in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have added the lightning web component into utility bar and after the save button it should be able to auto close the utility bar.

I have searched through the web but haven't got an answer on how to do that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported yet in LWC.

> Bring modern, blazing-fast Lightning web components (LWC) into the
>   utility bar by adding the lightning__UtilityBar target to your LWC‘s
>   meta configuration. **LWC utilities don’t yet support APIs or being used
>   as background utility items**.

[Please refer](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_console_lwc_utility.htm)

In the Aura components, there is an API for it.

**HTML**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="utilitybar" />
    <lightning:button label="Minimize Utility" onclick="{! c.minimizeUtility }" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    minimizeUtility : function(component, event, helper) {
        var utilityAPI = component.find("utilitybar");
        utilityAPI.minimizeUtility();
    }
})
```

One possible solution I can think of is wrapping the Lightning web component in the Aura component.

Comment: Rahul, Is it supported in LWC now?

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat I think its not yet supported, as per the linked document.

Comment: Ok Rahul, thanks